# Pinch Gestures - PinchOut Xcode iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview, gesture

I want to limit my View to scale only when a UIPinchGesture "pinch out is detected".
This is my code, it doesn't work as it doesn't limit the UIPinchGesture to only Pinch out & not Pinch In, it gets detected with both Pinch out and pinch in. 
Thanks in Advance! Daniel

```
-(void)PinchOutGesture {

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *longPress_gr1 = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doAction1:)];

//pinch out//
if(longPress_gr1.scale > 1) {


     [View addGestureRecognizer:longPress_gr1];
    //something happens
}


//Pinch in
if(longPress_gr1.scale < 1) {

    View = nil;
    //nothing happens

  }

}



- (void)doAction1:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {


    View.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];

    View.frame = CGRectMake(30, 64, 260, 334);
    View.alpha = 0.5;


    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Look at the `scale` property of the pinch gesture. If it is less than 1.0 then it is a pinch-in gesture, greater than 1.0 and it is a pinch-out gesture.

Comment: I figured it out... I had typed in the code the wrong spot. The scale property works.